# Compiling TCL libraries with TCL_MEM_DEBUG

Tags: tcl

I compiled TCL libraries with mem flag. But when i tried to use the libraries on my application i couldn't see any message in the console. will the trace messages out to standardard output(terminal) or will there be any log files to log the messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compile Tcl with the memory debugging enabled (using a Posix configuration style, this means that you passed in `--enable-symbols=mem` or `--enable-symbols=all` to `configure`; I'm not certain about what happens with Windows) there is a substantial amount of extra checking of memory allocation handling by default, *and* an extra Tcl command — [`memory`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/memory.htm) — is defined. Some `memory` subcommands do cause messages to be written to `stderr`; you'll need to be running inside a suitable console in order to see them, and this can be something of an issue on Windows if you are not aware of it. Other commands will dump things to a named file.

FWIW, when developing Tcl I usually build with `--enable-symbols=all` *except* when doing performance testing. The various debugging options are known to have substantial impacts on the speed of Tcl's implementation (which is why it is a compile option rather than being always present, and consequently why the interface is rather rougher than for the rest of Tcl).